# Laravel Nova: How to create a custom field and its crud methods?

Tags: php, laravel, image, base64, laravel-nova

I want to create a custom field for my Laravel Nova application. Thanks to Laracast I already figured out how I can to this ([here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-nova-mastery/episodes/14)). But I don't know how to edit the create, update and delete method and sadly I also haven't found anything about it on google...

The reason why I need to edit those functions is because I am using spatie/media-library to take care about my images I upload. Now I want to add a textfield editor to my Laravel Nova Recourse which can also handle images. However, those images should be added to the spatie/media-library and when updating or deleting the recourse, the image should of course also be deleted...

I have implemented such kind of function in my front end already with the quill editor. Users have the possibility to create comments and upload images as well within the comments. The images are send as base64 strings within my text field to my controller which then is taking care about saving the base64 image to my spatie/media-library.

Any idea how I can do the same with Laravel Nova?

Kind regards and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this package to implement media library in Laravel Nova

https://github.com/ebess/advanced-nova-media-library

Comment: But this is just a tool to manage my spatie media library. What I want is an text editor which is capable to upload images within the text